# How to alert the value using $this in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code and i want to alert the value of "first div" when i click the button on the first object and "second div" when i click the button on the 2nd object. .

How will i do it ? thanks :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).closest('.rel-wrap').find('.my-div').text;
    alert(selected);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">

  <div class="rel-wrap">
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="click me">
    <div class="my-div">
      first div
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rel-wrap">
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="click me">
    <div class="my-div">
      second div
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why alert? If it is for debugging, then thats a terrible approach - instead use console.log and similar functions. If its a purpose, im just curious what it could possibly be? ___

W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp ___ Chrome:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging ___ Stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: Hello @DanielBrose. Yes i use it for debugging . I also use console.log. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To get innerText of an element you need to use `text()` method, not the property
2. You can use `next()`, no need of traversing to the parent to get the interested element

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).next('.my-div').text();
    alert(selected);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">

  <div class="rel-wrap">
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="click me">
    <div class="my-div">
      first div
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rel-wrap">
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="click me">
    <div class="my-div">
      second div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```